# flashbuilder 4 won't copy an xml file in release build

Tags: xml, apache-flex, resources

I have my own conf.xml file (src/conf/conf.xml) consists some properties (alphas, colors, etc). When i try to export release build, I see list of files which not includes that file. Why? When i run my application at debug it file places in "bin-debug" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Look in Project - Properties - Flex Compiler - Additional Compiler Arguments. If it's there like a services-config file or something it will get embeded.

If not, try cleaning the Project and making another release build.

If that still doesn't do it, change the name from config to something else as config.xml could be a special name that gets the XML file embeded in the release build.

Comment: I try out all 3 ways. Result is:
That is my additional arguments string: "-locale en_US -managers flash.fonts.AFEFontManager"

While cleaning project, flahbuilder removes all files from bin-debug folder (it should be) but after this the "config" folder into "bin-debug" still empty. So my conf.xml ("conf1.xml", etc (i try different names)) copies into "bin-debug" only when i rename it into "src" folder. Sorry for my ugly english

Comment: It's very strangous behavior... i think renaming of package "config" to "conf" are works but it isn't(
So renaming not working, cleaning not working, i not understand what do u mean about compiller additional arguments...

Comment: seems then i "make" an mistake in some place of the project (unclosed mxml-tag, for example) the xml config file copies into bin-debug and after it "export release build" offers to me conf/conf.xml file to include into release set. It looks like a bug into flashbuilder...

Comment: Additional Compier Arguments are the ones you wrote above, so not that. If you have an MXML error Flash Builder will not let you export so it's not this either.

Try making a new Project and copying the files there.

If all else fails, you can just manually copy the config.xml to your release folder if it's not an AIR Application.

Also be careful that you do not embed the XML file somewhere in your code.

Comment: it's Air application=) But I allways have an oportunity to copy files manual. THere are 2 ways I embeding the xml file:
1: <mx:XML id="conf" source="../conf/conf.xml"/>

2: [Embed(source="./conf/conf.xml", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private static var Conf : Class;

And the 2nd was added after I noticed strange behavior of flashbuilder...

And about mxml error. If i have an error, when I build project the xml file copies into bin-debug